# Controller Method not getting called

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.0

I have a method in `MyController`

```
public function myMethod($id) {
 dd($id);
}
```

The `routes.php` file

```
Route::post('path1/{obj-id}/path2', 'MyController@myMethod');
Route::resource('path1', 'MyController');
```

In the view file, I am calling the method through a form on submit

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['MyController@myMethod', $myObject->id]]) !!}
```

Now the problem is, every time I click on `Submit` I get a `404` error. The URL in the address bar changes to `path1/1/path2` as expected, but I get `404`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: change "Route::post" to "Route::any" and check the result.

Comment: @salar same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution myself.
Turns out one cannot have a dash (`-`) inside `{}` in one's routes.

My route in `routes.php` was initially

```
Route::post('path1/{obj-id}/path2', 'MyController@myMethod');
```

I changed it to

```
Route::post('path1/{id}/path2', 'MyController@myMethod');
```

and now everything works fine.

Sorry for missing the `-` in the original question. Thank you all who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with your route .

`Route::post('path1/{id}', 'MyController@myMethod');`

And in View, You missed the Post method . Change your view to below

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['MyController@myMethod', $myObject->id, 'method' => 'post']]) !!}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: By default the method is `POST`. Still I tried your solution and got the same error.

Comment: Ok . Check if the Value exists in $myObject->id or hard code that value such as 1  and  try with only one path in  route , Route::post('path1/{id}', 'MyController@myMethod');

Comment: Yes, there is a value of `1` in `myObject->id`. It's also reflected in the URL `path1/1/path2`

Comment: I think You missed the double braces in view {{ }} and remove exclamatory. Your code should be like {{ Form::open(['action' => ['MyController@myMethod', $myObject->id, 'method' => 'post' ]]) }} . And also Get is the default method for form element ! so include  method type also !

Comment: In Laravel 5, you can't use double curly braces {{ }} for Form:open(). Because, `Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks.`

Comment: Thanks @linuxartisan ! otherwise leave that confusion and use like this <form  role="form" method="POST" action="{{ ( 'MyController@myMethod' ) }}"> //submit button here</form>

Answer (score 0):

You can give your route a name and use this name in form

```
Route::post('path1/{id}/path2', [
    'as' => 'myroute', 'uses' => 'MyController@myMethod'
]);
```

Now use it at your form like this

```
Form::open(array('route' => array('myroute', $myObject->id)))
```

Comment: Still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `{!! Form::open(['action' => ['MyController@myMethod', $myObject->id]]) !!}`, you need to use any of these:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'path1/'.$myObject->id.'/path2']) !!}
```

Or, if you use `Name routes` i.e. `mymethod.update`, you can do it easily with that:

```
{!! Form::open(['routes' => ['mymethod.update', $myObject->id]]) !!}
```

BTW, if you really want to use `'action'`, you need to change your url like this in your `routes.php` file:

```
Route::post('path1/path2/{id}', 'MyController@myMethod');
Route::resource('path1', 'MyController');
```

Hope this help!

Comment: That didn't work either. I don't think the problem lies in `Route::post('path1/{id}/path2', 'MyController@myMethod');`. I have other similar routes that work properly.